# Custom TFS Build Log Files

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have a TFS build in a Git team project that uses the default template. It builds a .proj file containing a single target that executes a .PS1 file in Powershell.exe.

The .PS1 generates its own log file. I have been trying to figure out how to get this file to copy to the drop directory \logs folder. From what I can tell, TFS only copies specific files to this output directory:

- ActivityLog.AgentScope.[id].xml
- ActivityLog.xml
- build.log

Anyone tried getting custom logging info to this directory? I tried writing to build.log but that failed with errors.

Comment: What is the powershell script doing?

Comment: It is running a gulp task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PowerShell you can easily execute Host-Write to write to the Build log. All of the standers output methods are captured, although you need to use the "-verbose" tag to get the text to always write.

Comment: Thanks! That simplifies things quite a bit! Although I am using Write-Output due to [this blog](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 2):

I like @MrHinsh's answer better than mine, but I found that you can write to a file at this location: `$(TF_BUILD_DROPLOCATION)\logs` during build.

I assumed that since the path doesn't exist until the log files are copied it would not work. But it does... the TFS/MSBuild log files are simply merged in. And it even seemed to work with a name conflict. For example, if your file is named build.log, MSBuild's will be renamed to build.01.log.